# <math.h> math module is not working for me in C, i am using VSCodium in linux

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, math.h, vscodium

so my code ran smoothly in codium with the extensions when i was only working with stdio.h, but when i tried to use math.h module in my program i am unable to run it, this is what i get as error:

Executing task: /bin/bash -c gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -g3 -O0 -c /home/suvansh/Documents/Cstuff/new.c -o ./build/Debug/new.o && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -g3 -O0   ./build/Debug/new.o -o ./build/Debug/outDebug

/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/13/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: ./build/Debug/new.o: in function `main': /home/suvansh/Documents/Cstuff/new.c:97:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to` pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

- The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -g3 -O0 -c /home/suvansh/Documents/Cstuff/new.c -o ./build/Debug/new.o && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -g3 -O0   ./build/Debug/new.o -o ./build/Debug/outDebug'" failed to launch (exit code: 1).
- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

when i comment the line which uses the math module, my code works fine

i tried running gcc in terminal (i have never ran or compiled C in terminal i have always used codium or online compiler i tried this after some googling) so i tried "gcc -c new.c -lm -o new.o"
(new.c is my file name) i was expecting for the code to run but nothing happened, after i typed it it just went to the next line but a new, new.o file was made.

i need a solution on how to actually fix this, is it a problem inside vscodium or am i missing something to install in my system ?

Comment: `-lm` is missing from that first auto-generated "executing task". I don't know how to get it included there, but that's the cause of the linker error.

Comment: Ditch the IDE, use the command line. The correct command is `gcc -o new new.c -lm` (no `-c`). Or you can do it in two stages: `gcc -c new.c` and then `gcc -o new new.o -lm`. Look up what each argument to gcc does.

Comment: Terminology: headers such as `math.h` are not conventionally called "modules" in C jargon.  The usage is reminiscent of Python, and if you're coming from that direction then you need to understand the the C preprocessor's `#include` directive performs a vastly different function from a Python's `import` statement.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI ok thanks it worked for me, i just did not know you have to run "./new" to run the file when using terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i got it fixed with help from the comments, i wasnt aware you have to run "./new" to execute it and that i have to include "-lm" after "gcc -o new new.c". I read through the documentation of the extension and figured out how to add extra arguments to the gcc compiler so now it works in the IDE as well and i know to run it from the terminal too. apparently you have to edit the settings.json in the .vscode directory which is created locally, i had to add

```
"C_Cpp_Runner.compilerArgs":[
    "-lm"
],
```

i had to add "-lm" in the settings.json and when i tried running it after, it worked properly.

note that i am not using the C/C++ extension from microsoft, i am using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=franneck94.c-cpp-runner
so this fix only works for this.